# Getting a count of data across all months

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a count of records grouped by a monthly basis from the entire table.

So for example I need:

```
June: 20 OR  6: 20

Jan: 18 or  1: 18
```

So far I have

```
$mquery = $db->query('SELECT MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(dateline)),YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(dateline)),
COUNT(*) as count FROM '.TABLE_PREFIX.'posts GROUP BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(dateline))');

    $count = $db->fetch_array($mquery);
    print_r($count);
```

Which returns only the current month and the count for the current month I need to output all months it can find as well as the count

Comment: `fetch_all` is required instead of `fetch_array`

Comment: $mquery = $db->query('SELECT MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(dateline)) as  mnth,YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(dateline)) as yr,
COUNT(*) as count FROM '.TABLE_PREFIX.'posts GROUP BY yr,mnth;
 Try this

Comment: what is the format in which date is stored in your column dateline. please specify it.

Comment: BTW: And don't forget also to group by year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in 2 ways:-

```
$count = $db->fetch_all($mquery);
print_r($count);
```

OR

```
while($count = $db->fetch_array($mquery)){
  print_r($count);
}
```

Comment: This seems to work but how would I go about accessing the data just in
[MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(dateline))]

Comment: @Paradigm when you use group by multiple rows of data are coming or i would say months with there count.
 when you do this $count = $db->fetch_array($mquery);
    print_r($count);
it fetches only this first row hence you can only see the one data only hence the solution given is correct.